# my view in not navigating to another view

Tags: ios, navigation

I have two views - one is  `viewcontroller` and another is `enterdetails` .

My question is my view- `enterdetails` is loading in the same view(`viewcontroller`) when I clicked `alertview` button it is not navigating to `enterdetails`

```
#import "enterDetails.h"

@interface enterDetails ()

@end

@implementation enterDetails

enterdetails.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImageView *tab_image=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    tab_image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar.jpeg"];
    [self.view addSubview:tab_image];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

viewcontroller.m (alertview)

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        enterDetails *det=[[enterDetails alloc]init];
        [self presentViewController:det animated:NO completion:nil];
    }

}

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@" Already Sucessfully Register"delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:@"enter", nil];

    [alert show];
     [alert release];
```

Comment: Have you set the UIAlertView delegate? and set it while showing UIAlertView to self?

Comment: show alert view code..

Comment: i already added delegate to self

Comment: and your having two different ViewControllers or you are using two views in the same xib?

Comment: no iam using different  viewcontrollers

Comment: i edited my code..see it once

Comment: @Ajay do u have any solution..please help me

Comment: check it using break point that execution goes there in condition (buttonIndex == 0) by clicking OK button. If execution is not reaching there.. then it might happen due to call to[alert release] just immediately after [alert show]. and still not able to load view then it might be different issue. Actually its working fine with me. But I am using ARC

Comment: execution reaches the break point at (buttonindex==0)

Comment: :(   its not working for me  iam not using ARC

Comment: Are you using a xib for enterDetails or are you creating a view programatically? Which class is enterDetails subclassing, a pure UIViewController?

Comment: Try using this enterDetails *det=[[enterDetails alloc]initWithNibName:@"enterDetails" bundle:nil];

Comment: ajay thanls for fast replay